# systemd to lock screen on suspend as X session owner?

Tags: systemd

I have recently moved to using `systemd` to manage power control.

In order to get my screen to be locked when returning from suspend, I created `/etc/systemd/system/i3lock.service` with these contents

```
[Unit]
Description=i3lock
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=fommil
Type=forking
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/i3lock -c 000000

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

and then ran `systemctl enable i3lock.service`.

But this means the lock is always for the `fommil` user.

How does one set up a service that will run the screen locker as the user who currently owns the X session?

Comment: I don't think that's a job for the system **systemd**. And the user is not the only problem, the `DISPLAY` environment variable is another one.

Comment: You might want to try [i3lock-wait-for-suspend](https://gist.github.com/olvaffe/06af825f69bd058e0116) by olvaffe or [i3lock-wait-for-suspend](https://gist.github.com/kanru/ad057292af8249a7cacf) by kanru.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a user unit for that instead of a system unit. Put it in `/etc/systemd/user/`, if you want it to be available (not enabled) for all users, or `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/`, if you want it to be available for that user only.

Then you can remove the `User=` option (and probably the `Environment=` option as well, you can run `systemctl show-environment` as the current user to see if the required env vars have already been imported), and then enable the service with `systemd --user enable i3clock`. (Or `sudo systemd --global enable i3lock` if it's available for all users *and you want it to be **enabled for all users***.)